# How to store two space-separated variables as one element in a list to output the element later as integer datatypes

Tags: python, list, integer

I'd like to append two space-separated integer variables to a list as an element, then later output the contents of the list on newlines. For example,

```
storage = a + 3, b + 3
lst.append(storage)
```

Later, when printing the elements of the list, I get:

```
for i in lst:
   print(i)

>>> (4, 7)
>>> (3, 6)
>>> (7, 7)
```

Instead, I'd like the output to be exactly:

```
>>> 4 7 
>>> 3 6
>>> 7 7
```

separated on newlines as a space-separated pair of integers without commas and not part of a list. In addition, I also input singular integers between the pairs and would like to output them on a newline as well:

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

Expected output:

```
>>> 1
>>> 4 7 
>>> 3 6
>>> -1
>>> 7 7
>>> 3
```

How can I do this without using list comprehension/mapping/defined functions/importing?

Comment: You don't have "space separated variables", you have tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test each element to see if it's a tuple, and if it is, use the `*` operator to spread it as multiple args to `print()`.

```
>>> lst = [1, (4, 7), (3, 6), -1, (7, 7), 3]
>>> for i in lst:
...     if isinstance(i, tuple):
...         print(">>>", *i)
...     else:
...         print(">>>", i)
...
>>> 1
>>> 4 7
>>> 3 6
>>> -1
>>> 7 7
>>> 3
```

Comment: other option is import collection an use isinstance(i, Iterable). In case that the variables could be list or tuples and not only tuples. But will separate the strings to characthers